# Python to print no. of characters in a word document (.docx)

Tags: python-3.x, document, pywin32, cpu-word, win32com

I have a Word Document and I want to print no. of characters in the document.

I wrote the code but this is not working !!

```
from win32com.client import constants, Dispatch
import os

word= Dispatch('Word.Application')
cwd = os.getcwd()
os.chdir(cwd)
mondoc=word.Documents.Open(r"12a.docx")
numberofchars=mondoc.Characters.Count
for numero_caractere in range (1,int(numberofchars)+1):
    character = mondoc.Characters.Item(numero_caractere)
    try:
        print(character)
    except:
        print("cannot read character")
        pass
numberofchars=mondoc.Characters.Count
```

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'Characters'

Any Way or Any Library to Count number of characters in a word document ? **(.doc)** or **(.docx)**

***How to print no. of characters for multiple word documents ?
I have selected the word documents using GUI Dialog Box.***
***How to save no. of characters for all the word documents as variables*** ***?***

Comment: Looks like you haven't opening the Document successfully. Double-check the name and path.

Comment: i have changed the directory to my current working directory and gave the file name. the file is opening but characters attribute is absent in win32com

Comment: The error code suggests the mondoc variable is `None`, ie the document object isn't valid.

Comment: Can You Tell me Exactly how to fix the code ?

Answer (score 0):

This kind of behaviour comes when there is already an instance of Word running in the background. In that case the `Dispatch()` call connects you to the running instance, not a new instance of Word. You are failing to open the file (hence the `mondoc` variable is `None`), but Word wasn't letting you know by throwing an exception.

For some reason, attaching to a running instance seems to prevent the exception thrown by `Documents.Open()` from getting to your code. Open Task Manager to check if any instances of 'Microsoft Word' are running: if there are, End Task on them.

Better code is this, as it tidies up the Word instance when it is finished.

```
import win32com.client as wc

word= wc.Dispatch('Word.Application')

doc = None

try:
    doc = word.Documents.Open(r'12a.docx')

    if doc is not None:
        #Do whatever you want with the doc
        print('Word count:',doc.Characters.Count)

        doc.Close()
    else:
        print('Could not open file')

except:
    print('Word Exception')

word.Quit()
```

During development it may help if you add these lines after the `Dispatch()` call:

```
word.Visible=True
word.DisplayAlerts = wc.constants.wdAlertsAll
```

Then you will see any message boxes that Word displays. Also, it is better to supply the complete file path (using `os.path.join()`) rather than rely on changing the working directory.

Comment: Word Exception

Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: Documents.Open() Does not work for Multiple word documents. How to store Characters for multiple word documents as variables ? Note:- I want to select multiple word documents using GUI Dialog Box